# How to avoid too many threads when using tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tornado, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I'm using `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor` to change a synchronous function to asynchrounous, but it turns out that each time the function is called, there is a thread created but not killed.

Here's an mimimal reproducible example (at least reproducible on my machine):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          

import time
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

def slow_func():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('slow func returned')
    return 'succ\n'

class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        print('GET called')
        try:
            result = await tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, slow_func)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        self.write(result)
        print('GET returned')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', TestHandler),
    ]).listen(3000)
    print('Serving at 3000')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Each request to this `TestHandler` will create a new thread to run the `slow_func`, but the thread remains after the function returns. I can see them in `ps H` and it creates new threads until it hits ulimit. My environment here is:

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 18 10:29:08 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.4
$ pip3 show tornado
Name: tornado
Version: 6.0.3
Summary: Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library, originally developed at FriendFeed.
Home-page: http://www.tornadoweb.org/
Author: Facebook
Author-email: python-tornado@googlegroups.com
License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Location: /xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

`tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor` uses `concurrent.futures.Executor` and returns an awaitable `Future` object. [1][2][3]

- [1]: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor
- [2]: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/ioloop.html#IOLoop.run_in_executor
- [3]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

What are the threads doing after the functions return? Why aren't they killed after the future object resolves? How should I avoid this?

Comment: I have figured out why other people doesn't encounter this problem: The default size of `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is 5 times CPU cores. Here I have 384 cores but `ulimit -u` is only 1024.

Comment: FYI this is being changed in Python 3.8 to use a maximum of 32 threads by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run_in_executor` takes a [`concurrent.futures.Executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects) object as the first argument.

You can create an executor and limit the size of the thread pool:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)

IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(executor, slow_func)
```

Comment: Your solution works. Requests will be queued when thread pool is full. Thank you very much. What is the purpose of such design except reusing threads? Why don't the threads exit automatically?

Comment: @simonmysun In Python, threads exit when their `run()` method exits. But in this case, `run_in_executor` uses `ThreadPoolExecutor` by default if you don't provide your own executor. So the threads don't exit and stay alive because `ThreadPoolExecutor` is managing them by default.

Comment: yes thank you for the information. Finally I found out that it has a default limit of 5 * number of cpu cores while my ulimit -u is only 1024. so that's why most users doesn't reach the ulimit.